# Print selected text in macOS using Automator?

Tags: macos, printing, automator

How can I use Automator (macOS 10) to create a workflow for printing selected text? I'd like to set up a sequence that works across all applications? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a workflow that saves the selected text to a file, prints the file and then moves the file to the trash. Here's how:

1. Open Automator, create a new workflow and select Service as a type
2. The workflow should receive selected text in any application so leave those as they are.
3. Add “New Text File” action to the workflow.
4. In the File Format drop-down, you can choose rich text, if you wish to preserve formatting of the text. Change the filename in the Save as field to something you like.
5. Add “Print Finder Items” action to the workflow.
6. Choose the printer you want to use.
7. Add “Move Finder Items to Trash” action to the workflow. This will move the previously created text file to the Trash.
8. Save the workflow with a descriptive name, eg. “Print with default printer”.

Test and use your workflow by selecting text in any application, right-clicking it and selecting your workflow from the Services menu. You can also assign a keyboard shortcut for your service in System Preferences, Keyboard, Shortcuts.

Here's [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVbGl.png) how the workflow should look like when ready.